# How to archive all saved data contained in a RSS feed on feedly?

Tags: rss, feedly

So I know I could export all the data contained in the RSS feeds on Google Reader once it shut down. I'm just wondering - is it possible to do the same for feedly? If so, how?

Comment: Do you mean a specific feed(s) or everything on feedly?

Comment: Just a specific feed.